# NGINX, How to use same location path for different target folder?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

i am trying to use same location path in nginx.

```
location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

        location  /  {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
```

but it is rendering app folder.

i am trying to achieve rendering 'main' folder html file in case of '/' path and  'app' folder html file in case of any other path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same location, you need to use different location for different folder. Even if you see "try_files" which use multiples points, "location" is different.

However, you can use multiple location like media in "/media" and "/" for html content or other.

**Example**

```
location /media {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location  /  {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```